# Undeclared identifier Objective-C in Objective-C++ AppDelegate.mm

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, react-native, objective-c++

I try to import module "NfcManager" (react-native-nfc-manager) in "AppDelegate.mm" in react-native 0.68 app

But error `Use of undeclared identifier "NfcManager"`

In react-native 0.64 "AppDelegate.m" all work fine

How to declare or use this class in Objective-c++ *.mm?

I try to rename "NfcManager.m" to "*.mm" but same result.

I dont know C++ and C

```
 
        // AppDelegate.mm

        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
        restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)
        (NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {

        [NfcManager application:application
                continueUserActivity:userActivity
                restorationHandler:restorationHandler];  // error
           ...
        }

        // NfcManager.h

        @interface NfcManager : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule> { ... }

        // NfcManager.m

        @implementation NfcManager { ... }
```

**UPDATE**

All work if import "NfcManager.h" to "AppDelegate.h" not to "AppDelegate.mm" like in previous version with Objective-C "AppDelegate.m"

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing

```
#import "NfcManager.h"
```

in your `AppDelegate.mm`.

Comment: No. Import on his place

Comment: What do you mean? Do you already have the necessary `#import` in your `AppDelegate.mm`? If so, then there's vital information missing in your question.

Comment: But you take me some idea, and when I import "NfcManager.h" to "AppDelegate.h" error is gone

Comment: I indicated that I was trying to import - this means that there is an import

Comment: maybe you import in #if statement